# What is a Melanomexstirpation (type of operation)

Tags: single-word-request

Does anyone know the English equivalent of a Melanomexstirpation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about German Language. »Melanomexstirpation« is a medical term in Latin language. This Question has nothing to do with German Language.

Comment: _Melanomexstirpation_ is a compound noun. You may find the components _[Melanom](http://www.duden.de/node/703303/revisions/1217165/view)_ and _[Exstirpation](http://www.duden.de/node/756473/revisions/1189633/view)_ in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to surgically remove a melanoma (skin cancer consisting of melanocytes). This can be part of a bigger operation which also includes the removal of the sentinel node, but it can also be performed as the only step.

Exstirpation in this context is equivalent to Exzision, but it sounds more 'complete' or 'radical' to a doctor's ear, as Exstirpation usually refers to taking out a full organ, like the spleen or a kidney.